# Possible values of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation looks like this:

$$x'={-tx\over (t+1)},$$ $x(0)=2$

The solution is

$$x(t)={2(t+1)\over e^t},$$ $t\in\mathbb R,$

and I can't figure out why $t$ isn't limited to $(-1,+\infty)$, since in the separable function $g(t) = t/(t+1)$, $t$ is obviously limited to $(-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,+\infty)$.

Thanks for any kind of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution $y$ to differential equation $x'(t)=\dfrac{-tx(t)}{t+1}$ is, by definition, a function $y$ defined on a non trivial interval $I$ such that $\forall t\in I\left(y'(t)=\dfrac{-ty(t)}{t+1}\right)$.

The function $x\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, t\mapsto 2(t+1)e^{-t}$ isn't a solution to the given ODE simply because it isn't true that $x'(-1)=\dfrac{-(-1)x(-1)}{-1+1}$ (nor false, for that matter).

Thus a maximal solution to the starting IVP is $y\colon (-1,+\infty)\to \mathbb R, t\mapsto 2(t+1)e^{-t}$.